# How to load dynamic locations data to google heatmap in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am working on the live project which is developed in Angular.js & MongoDB. Now I am implementing [Google Heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) static heatmap into my HTML view and it's displaying properly.

Now I have Created one API to get users location details from my mongo table. I have used ajax call to call my API URL and it's returning users locations data. Everything is working smoothly at this stage.

Let's try to share my code first:

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Google Heatmap</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript

```
var map, yellowHeatmap, redHeatmap;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {lat: 37.775, lng: -122.434},
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    yellowHeatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: getYelloPoints(),
        map: map
    });

    redHeatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: getRedPoints(),
        map: map
    });

    var yellowGradient = [
        'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0)',
        'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)'
    ]
    yellowHeatmap.set('gradient', yellowHeatmap.get('gradient') ? null : yellowGradient);

    var redGradient = [
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
        'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    ]
    redHeatmap.set('gradient', redHeatmap.get('gradient') ? null : redGradient);
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/user/getCountryMerchantYellowHeat',
    type: 'GET',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
        var length = data.data.length;
        getYelloPoints(data.data, length);
    }
});

function getYelloPoints(data, length) {
    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].address[0].lat, data[i].address[0].long);
        markers.push(location);
    }
}

function getRedPoints() {
    return [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.798719, -122.429092),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.798944, -122.429145)
    ];
}
```

If you noticed that I am calling `getYelloPoints()` function in ajax success to pass response data. I have double checked that I am getting all the data in `getYelloPoints()` function. Now problem is that when I am trying loop the data location is not displaying in the heatmap and at this stage, I don't know how to resolve map issue.

If used this loop and pass static location 10 times at same location so the map is working but if loop the data which are getting from the API something is wrong.

```
// THIS IS WORKING PERFECT WITH STATIC LOOP AND STATIC LOCATION
var markers = [];
for( var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(37.769544, -122.506104);
    markers.push(location);
}
return markers;
```

Do you know to load heatmap in angular.js?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is AngularJS tagged here? This is not a AngularJS application.

Comment: I have implemented heatmap in angular.js and finding a solution.

Comment: No, you didn't. There is no `ng-app` directive in your codes. You also use jQuery -> `$.ajax`. This isn't AngularJS.

Comment: I am not sharing because the code is very bing so explained the main things only.

Comment: OK, sorry so. I can't help you since this is not AngularJS. Don't expect us to rewrite your code and migrate it as an AngularJS application.

Comment: @lin No problem.